# Iterating JObject Keys

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following `JObject` as return by https://gate.io/api2#trade API. How do I iterate through each key which is a separate coin also get its value.

I tried to parse it using Newtonsoft `JObject` Parse like this:

```
var coinData = JObject.Parse(@"{
    ""result"": ""true"",
    ""available"": {
        ""BTC"": ""0.83337671"",
        ""LTC"": ""94.364"",
        ""ETH"": ""0.07161"",
        ""ETC"": ""82.35029899""
    },
    ""locked"": {
        ""BTC"": ""0.0002"",
        ""YAC"": ""10.01""
    }
}")["available"];

foreach (JToken item in coinData)
{
    item.Key
}
```

but then `JToken` doesn't give access to key values. I don't know how to further parse it.

JSON received from gateio api:

```
{
    "result": "true",
    "available": {
        "BTC": "0.83337671",
        "LTC": "94.364",
        "ETH": "0.07161",
        "ETC": "82.35029899"
    },
    "locked": {
        "BTC": "0.0002",
        "YAC": "10.01"
    }
}
```

EDIT: Should I break it with ':' while iterating in loop? This is working if i break it and replace quotes.

```
foreach (JToken item in coinData)
{
    var data = item.ToString().Replace("\"", String.Empty).Split(':');
}
```

var data has two parts, 1 => coin name, 2 => balance.

Is there any other legit way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JToken` is base class for all types of json tokens. In your case though you want only json properties, so you need to filter by more narrow type - `JProperty`. You can filter to include only property tokens like this:

```
foreach (var item in coinData.OfType<JProperty>()) {
    string coinName = item.Name;
    // to parse as decimal
    decimal balance = item.Value.Value<decimal>();
    // or as string
    string balanceAsString = item.Value.Value<string>();
}
```

Comment: @stuartd OP enumerates only `available` property (in his code example if you scroll to the right you'll see `["available"]`)

Comment: foreach (var item in coinData["available"].OfType<JProperty>()) {}

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest being very explicit about expecting the result of "available" to be another object, by casting to `JObject`. You can then call `Properties()` to get its properties, each as a `JProperty`. Here's a complete example to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()        
    {
        string json = @"{
            'result': 'true',
            'available': {
                'BTC': '0.83337671',
                'LTC': '94.364',
                'ETH': '0.07161',
                'ETC': '82.35029899'
            },
            'locked': {
                'BTC': '0.0002',
                'YAC': '10.01'
            }
        }".Replace('\'', '"');
        JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
        JObject coins = (JObject) root["available"];
        foreach (JProperty property in coins.Properties())
        {
            string name = property.Name;
            string value = (string) property.Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name}; Value: {value}");
        }    
    }
}
```