# Parse JSON where node has numeric value

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

How do I parse the following JSON to get the value of `TestCycleName`. The challenge is in identifying the root node since it starts with a number.

My implementation will be in C# using JSON.net

```
{
  "URL": "rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=##projectId##&versionId=##versionId##",
  "Method": "GET",
  "Parameters": {
    "1": {
      "VersionName": "Custom Pipes Development",
      "TestCycleName": "SetMaxFutureDateFromCustomerField_Mobile"
    },
    "2": {
      "VersionName": "Recurring payments 1.5",
      "TestCycleName": "Internet Full Regression Pack - Mobile"
    },
    "3": {
      "VersionName": "Customer Profile Phase 1.5",
      "TestCycleName": "Customer Profile Regression Pack - Desktop"
    },
    "4": {
      "VersionName": "Customer Profile Phase 1.5",
      "TestCycleName": "Customer Profile E2E Pack - Desktop"
    },
    "5": {
      "VersionName": "Customer Profile Phase 1.5",
      "TestCycleName": "Customer Profile Regression Pack - Mobile"
    },
    "6": {
      "VersionName": "Internet Phase 1.2",
      "TestCycleName": "Internet API Regression Pack"
    },
    "7": {
      "VersionName": "Internet Phase 1.2",
      "TestCycleName": "Internet GUI Regression Pack - Desktop"
    },
    "8": {
      "VersionName": "Internet Phase 1.2",
      "TestCycleName": "Internet GUI Regression Pack - Mobile"
    },
    "9": {
      "VersionName": "Internet Phase 1.2",
      "TestCycleName": "Regression Library Admin Tool - E2E Tests"
    },
    "10": {
      "VersionName": "Internet Phase 1.2",
      "TestCycleName": "Regression Library E2E Tests - Mobile"
    },
    "11": {
      "VersionName": "Recurring payments 1.5",
      "TestCycleName": "[Internet] Autopay API Automation Regression Pack"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Its a dictionary, so in your classes, just use a Dictionary<Something>

Comment: Copy this json string, then go to Visual studio,_**Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes**_

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552708/how-to-parse-json-with-number-as-a-key

Comment: If you can, get the people that made the JSON to change it so it returns an array rather than a list of separate objects.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string or int, Parameter>` for `Parameters` as recommended in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try codes as follows:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"URL\": \"rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=##projectId##&versionId=##versionId##\",\"Method\": \"GET\",\"Parameters\": {\"1\": {\"VersionName\": \"Custom Pipes Development\",\"TestCycleName\": \"SetMaxFutureDateFromCustomerField_Mobile\"},\2"\": {\"VersionName\": \"Recurring payments 1.5\",\"TestCycleName\": \"Internet Full Regression Pack - Mobile\"}}}";

        var parameters = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["Parameters"];

        foreach (var item in parameters.OfType<JProperty>())
        {
            var innerObject = JObject.Parse(item.Value.ToString())["TestCycleName"];

            Console.WriteLine(innerObject.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Parameters` is a dictionary, so you can write something like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public string VersionName { get; set; }
    public string TestCycleName { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize it:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json_string);

//You can get your TestCycleNames for example in string array
string[] testCycleName = result.Parameters.Select(p => p.Value.TestCycleName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (not tested of-course, but you can debug it):

```
// You get Parameters object
var parameters = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["Parameters"];

// parameters can further be accessed via key/value pair using JProperty
foreach( var item in parameters.OfType<JProperty>()){

  // each item has a key and a value i.e item.Name and item.Value, 
  // key = numeric in your data, value is a json object.
  // take object and further parse it to reach TestCycleName

  var innerObject = JObject.Parse(item.Value.ToString())["TestCycleName"];

  Console.WriteLine(innerObject.ToString());

}
```

I had something similar, check it out here: [Iterating JObject Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446874/iterating-jobject-keys)

Comment: getting this error cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToke' to string at item.value

Comment: @mach As I said, I wrote it here in Stackoverflow, didn't test it. Updated my answer. Need to convert Value to string because JObject.Parse takes string to parse.