# Parse JSON containing unnamed node

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have the following JSON payload.

The challenge is to fetch the name value and the corresponding root node number (3925 or 3932) since this node is unnamed.

I am using C#

```
"3925": {
        "totalExecutions": 2,
        "endDate": "",
        "description": "",
        "totalExecuted": 2,
        "started": "",
        "versionName": "Custom Pipes Development",
        "expand": "executionSummaries",
        "projectKey": "WUSDV007",
        "versionId": 22361,
        "environment": "",
        "totalCycleExecutions": 2,
        "totalDefects": 0,
        "build": "",
        "createdBy": "mghosh",
        "ended": "",
        "name": "SetMaxFutureDateFromCustomerField_Mobile",
        "totalFolders": 0,
        "modifiedBy": "mghosh",
        "projectId": 17101,
        "createdByDisplay": "Mayukh Ghosh",
        "startDate": "",
        }
    }

"3932": {
        "totalExecutions": 2,
        "endDate": "",
        "description": "",
        "totalExecuted": 2,
        "started": "",
        "versionName": "Custom Pipes Development",
        "expand": "executionSummaries",
        "projectKey": "WUSDV007",
        "versionId": 22361,
        "environment": "",
        "totalCycleExecutions": 2,
        "totalDefects": 0,
        "build": "",
        "createdBy": "nkonda",
        "ended": "",
        "name": "WUSDV007-29779-Fee Validation",
        "totalFolders": 0,
        "modifiedBy": "nkonda",
        "projectId": 17101,
        "createdByDisplay": "Naveen Kumar Konda",
        "startDate": "",

    }
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: presently I am trying to fetch the root node but am stuck since it is unnamed

Comment: you could deserialize object to `Dictionary<string, object>` and then the `Keys`  will contain root nodes (3925, 3932 etc)

Comment: This is a dictionary, tadaa!!

Comment: Does the JSON not have an opening `{` and a closing `}`? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON where node has numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503111/parse-json-where-node-has-numeric-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try code as follows:

```
string jsonString = "{\"3925\": { \"totalExecutions\": 2, \"endDate\": \"\", \"description\": \"\", \"totalExecuted\": 2, \"started\": \"\", \"versionName\": \"Custom Pipes Development\", \"expand\": \"executionSummaries\", \"projectKey\": \"WUSDV007\", \"versionId\": 22361, \"environment\": \"\", \"totalCycleExecutions\": 2, \"totalDefects\": 0, \"build\": \"\", \"createdBy\": \"mghosh\", \"ended\": \"\", \"name\": \"SetMaxFutureDateFromCustomerField_Mobile\", \"totalFolders\": 0, \"modifiedBy\": \"mghosh\", \"projectId\": 17101, \"createdByDisplay\": \"Mayukh Ghosh\", \"startDate\": \"\" }}";

var parameters = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (var item in parameters.OfType<JProperty>())
{
   var innerObject = JObject.Parse(item.Value.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(innerObject.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is fetching only the inner node and not the number 3925